# Decode svg from memory ImageMagick

Tags: c++, imagemagick

How do I decode svg image from buffer? I know SVGs are just text but I don't know how to parse them to Magick::Image other than reading from disk.

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace Magick;

int main() {
    printf("EnableOpenCL ret: %d\n", Magick::EnableOpenCL());
    Magick::Image svgImage;
    svgImage.read("input.svg"); // first read file
    svgImage.magick("png"); // then specify PNG format
    svgImage.write("output.png");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would copy the buffer into Magick++'s `Magick::Blob` and pass it to `Magick::Image` constructor.

```cpp
Magick::Blob svgData(memory_ptr, memory_length);
Magick::Image svgImage(svgData, svgRenderSize, "SVG");
```

Where `memory_ptr` is the address of the svg data in memory, `memory_length` is the total byte size of `memory_ptr`, and `svgRenderSize` is `Magick::Geometry` instances the image size.